# How to compare Time set with Actual Time?

Tags: android, date, time

In my app you set the date/time with date/timePickers.

```
 SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
 Date datahora;
 datahora = (Date) formatter.parse(data);
```

I need to compare the time I set with the actual time of my phone. So I have tried this:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date datahora;
String datatmp = formatter.format(new Date(0));
 try {
    datahora = (Date) formatter.parse(data);
    if(datahora <= datatmp)
```

but I do know its wrong because it says it cant check `date > string` but I can't get to know how to check the actual time.

**EDIT**

LogCat

```
    10-08 20:14:07.453: E/AndroidRuntime(261): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    10-08 20:14:07.453: E/AndroidRuntime(261): java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col -1 failed
    10-08 20:14:07.453: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at android.database.CursorWindow.getString_native(Native Method)
    10-08 20:14:07.453: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:329)
    10-08 20:14:07.453: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:49)
    10-08 20:14:07.453: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at com.example.mensagem.Mensagenssalvas$1.onItemClick(Mensagenssalvas.java:59)
    10-08 20:14:07.453: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
    10-08 20:14:07.453: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3382)
    10-08 20:14:07.453: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1696)
    10-08 20:14:07.453: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    10-08 20:14:07.453: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    10-08 20:14:07.453: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at         android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    10-08 20:14:07.453: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    10-08 20:14:07.453: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    10-08 20:14:07.453: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    10-08 20:14:07.453: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    10-08 20:14:07.453: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    10-08 20:14:07.453: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the current date/time you just create a new `Date` object.

To compare dates you use `Date.compareTo()`:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date now = new Date();
int difference = now.compareTo(formatter.parse(data));
```

According to the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo%28java.util.Date%29), `difference` will be:

> the value 0 if the argument Date is equal to this Date; a value less
>   than 0 if this Date is before the Date argument; and a value greater
>   than 0 if this Date is after the Date argument.

```
if (difference == 0) {
    // the dates are equal
}
else if (difference < 0) {
    // the date is before now
}
else {
    // the date is after now
}
```

Comment: Oh, thanks can you post the code with the `if` statement? '-'

Comment: Alright, so im testing it inside a Service(dont know if changes something) so I used like this: `if(datahora == now) {` but no result came along. In the `Date()` I have a `0` inside the () and I tried with your code and my app crashed. the LogCat errors are in the Question EDIT.

Comment: You never want to do `if (datahora == now)` It will not work. You have to do `if (dateahora.compareTo(now) == 0)`. Don't put a 0 inside the Date() or it will January 1970, not now.

Comment: But, if i don't it says: `The constructor Date() is undefined` so i do have to put the 0 or 0,0,0 inside the ()

Comment: Are you importing the right Date? The docs say otherwise. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#Date()

Comment: Yes, it was wrong. now changed to util and worked, so i checked the app and still crashing

Answer (score 0):

But of Course you cant compare date with String.

try the following

```
Date datatmp = new Date();  

 try {
       datahora = (Date) formatter.parse(data);
        if( datahora.before(datatmp) )
.
.
```

if check the [Java Docs for Date](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#before%28java.util.Date%29) , it has `after` and `before` functions in addition to `compareTo` .

Best,
Rohan